# Bootstrap 4 columns are not reaching 100% height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I've noticed my columns aren't reaching 100% of the height of the row.

I was under the assumption that a feature for Bootstrap 4 was that the column height is always the same height as the row height as seen in this working example: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2016/11/boostrap-4-regular-vs-flex-grid/?5-column-height

For some reason I can't seem to produce the same result. I have tried using:

- align-items-stretch class on the row
- height: 100% on the columns
- flex: 1 with display:flex and flex-direction:column

I was wondering if someone could explain the proper setup method in making sure Bootstrap 4 columns reach 100% of the row height.

*(view in full page for accurate presentation)*

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.our-research {
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.our-research__container {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.our-research__content {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 35px;
  color: #999;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 500;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.our-research__image {
  position: relative;
  height: 175px;
}

.our-research__image .our-research__image-main {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="our-research bg--light-grey">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-stretch">
      <div class="col-10 col-sm-3 our-research__container">
        <div class="our-research__image">
          <img class="our-research__image-main" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="our-research__content">
          <h3 class="centered-heading__purple">Title</h3>
          <p>Suspendisse arcu dui commodo non ornare sed consequat</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-10 col-sm-3 our-research__container">
        <div class="our-research__image">
          <img class="our-research__image-main" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="our-research__content">
          <h3 class="centered-heading__purple">Tumor Bank</h3>
          <p>Suspendisse arcu dui commodo non ornare sed consequat</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-10 col-sm-3 our-research__container">
        <div class="our-research__image">
          <img class="our-research__image-main" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="our-research__content">
          <h3 class="centered-heading__purple">Research</h3>
          <p>Suspendisse arcu dui commodo non ornare sed consequat</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-10 col-sm-3 our-research__container">
        <div class="our-research__image">
          <img class="our-research__image-main" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="our-research__content">
          <h3 class="centered-heading__purple">Title</h3>
          <p>Suspendisse arcu dui.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have created a jsfiddle of my issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/eilawen/zjoeh0yp/12/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the height from our-research_container.

```
.our-research__container {         
     border: 1px solid blue;
     flex: 1;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. So just to confirm height: 100% doesn't work with display: flex? Also in the example provided above (http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2016/11/boostrap-4-regular-vs-flex-grid/?5-column-height) I've noticed that there is no need to specify display: flex and flex-direction: column on the col. Do you know why I have to specify it here?